wpFluent QueryBuilder fieds not inserted or updated
I use fluent form in wordpress and want to update or insert values in the table fluentform_entry_details
I can see changes in database but if I refresh my form on wordpress nothing changed
What did I miss ?
Thank you for your help
I tried things like
wpFluent()->table('fluentform_entry_details')->where('form_id', registrationFormId)->update(['field_value' => $maValue]);

OR
wpFluent()->table('fluentform_entry_details')->insert($data)

On a select on database my field is updated or inserted but on wordpress, on the entriy of my form it is not

Clear Cache: Clear all caches (browser, server, plugin).
Use Correct Context:
Insert
    $data = [
    'form_id' => $registrationFormId,
    'field_name' => 'your_field_name',
    'field_value' => $maValue,
    'entry_id' => $entryId
];
wpFluent()->table('fluentform_entry_details')->insert($data);

Update
wpFluent()->table('fluentform_entry_details')
    ->where('form_id', $registrationFormId)
    ->where('entry_id', $entryId)
    ->where('field_name', 'your_field_name')
    ->update(['field_value' => $maValue]);

Trigger Data Refresh:
do_action('fluentform/entry_updated', $entryId, $data);

Enable Debugging:
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);


Hi Umair, I tried but it doesn't work
